Unsure about using nested quantifiers
How do I use nested quantifers to translate this?

Every man gave every woman some toy.

I am not sure about my attempt:
M=man
W=woman
T=toy
G=x gave [t] to [y]
$\forall x(Mx \forall y My \rightarrow\exists w(Tw \& Gxtw)$

Why didn't you use restrictive comprehension, like $\forall m\in M \forall w\in W $..

What about $\forall x\forall y(Mx\land Wy\Rightarrow \exists w(Tw\land Gxtw))$?

In type theory/many-sorted logic: $\forall (m : M). \forall (w : W). \exists (t : T). G(m, t, w)$

@luce I see so the quantifier has to go outside

Required to translate:

Every man gave every woman some toy.

Consider instead: $~\forall x(Mx \to \forall y (Wy \to \exists t(Tt \land Gxyt))) $
where
Mx = x is a man
Wy = y is a woman
Tt = t is a toy
Gxyt = x gave y an object t

I see so I if I did
$\forall x\forall y(Mx\land Wy\Rightarrow \exists w(Tw\land Gxtw))$
Would it be wrong to put x and y in the antecedent

@FernandoMartinez What you have there is equivalent to what is in the answer (modulo that your G relation has things in a different order to the answer). The main difference is whether it is written in fully "exported" or "imported" form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Import%E2%80%93export_(logic). Also yours has the quantifiers moved to the front to allow the use of the conjunction.

@FernandoMartinez My suggestion seems to me to be more straightforward and easier to verify. Maybe it's just a matter of personal style, but I really can't tell if your version is right or wrong. It's confusing to me.

Ok I see thank did not know about import export

There are several things wrong with your:
$$\forall x(Mx \forall y My \rightarrow\exists w(Tw \& Gxtw)$$
First, it is not grammatical: you need a connective between  $Mx$ and  $\forall y My$. You also have an unequal number of open vs close parentheses.
Second, your $t$ variable in $Gxtw$ is not quantified, so that is a free variable. Now, I assume that you were aiming $t$ for the [t]oy, and the $w$ for the [w]oman (confusingly, you started to adopt $y$ for the woman ... which makes sense given that you use the $x$ for the man, but try to be consistent!). So that means that you need $\forall w$ instead of $\forall y$, and $\exists t$ instead of $\exists w$.
Third, again assuming you use $w$ for the woman, you want to use $Ww$ instead of $My$ (or instead of $Mw$). The woman needs to be a woman, not a man.
Fourth, you didn't specify the order of the arguments of the $G$ predicate, but I assume that your "G=x gave [t] to [y]" was meant to be the translation of $Gxty$, i.e. that the second argument of the predicate is the object being given by the first to the third.  That would also make it compatible with your use of $Gxtw$ in your sentence, again assuming that you aim to use $t$ for the toy and $w$ for the woman. So given the previous changes, you can actually leave $Gxtw$, but without those changes, you ended up saying that the man would be giving the woman to some unspecified object $t$!
Anyway, given the above suggestions, you can do:
$$\forall x(Mx \to \forall w Ww \rightarrow \exists t(Tt \land Gxtw)$$
or equivalently:
$$\forall x \forall w ((Mx \land Ww) \rightarrow \exists t(Tt \land Gxtw)$$
You can even pull out that existential:
$$\forall x \forall w \exists t((Mx \land Ww) \rightarrow (Tt \land Gxtw)$$
...but I do prefer any of the first two.

I see thanks for the answer

@FernandoMartinez You're welcome! :)
